# Can you run a for-loop in Python using MySQL returns as the condition?

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop

Is it possible to look up whose *active* flag is marked as *NULL* in a *wash* table of one db located on one server, then take these IDs and run a query on them in another db located at another server? What we want to have happen afterwards is to see if the latter query returns a number higher than 10, and then flag their *active* column as 1. It just seems that Python isn't doing anything with these IDs in an example I've tried out.

After some testing it seems like the for loop isn't iterating at all.

For Example:

```
hostname1 = 'xxx'
username1 = 'xxx'
password1 = 'xxx'
database1 = 'xxx'

hostname2 = 'yyy'
username2 = 'yyy'
password2 = 'yyy'
database2 = 'yyy'

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

# Connect to Dev HO
DevConnection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=hostname1,
        database=database1,
        user=username1,
        password=password1
    )
DevCursor = DevConnection.cursor()
DevCursorChange = DevConnection.cursor(buffered=True)

# Select our relevant CIDs
DevQuery = ('SELECT id FROM wash WHERE active IS NULL;')
DevCursor.execute(DevQuery)

# Connect to TAS db
TasConnection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=hostname2,
        database=database2,
        user=username2,
        password=password2
)
TasCursor = TasConnection.cursor()

# Select our relevant CIDs
TasQuery = ('SELECT SUM(last_seen - first_seen)/60/60 FROM atc_time WHERE first_seen >= 1546300800 AND last_seen <= 1577836800 AND cid = %s AND frequency != "199.998";')

for (id) in DevCursor:
    TasCursor.execute(TasQuery % id)
    if TasCursor.fetchone() > 10:
        DevCursorChange.execute('UPDATE wash SET active = 1 where ID = %s' % id)
    else:
        DevCursorChange.execute('UPDATE wash SET active = 0 where ID = %s' % id)

DevConnection.commit()
TasConnection.commit()
```

This does not return any error messages, as the code itself runs fine, but it's just not doing anything. After some debugging I've found out that *no* rows are being returned in the for loop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python database access APIs; but my first thought is to wonder what `TasCursor.execute` actually executing?

Comment: @Uueerdo I used that in an attempt to a workaround -- that func doesn't do anything, if you're looking at the ``TasCursorExecute=TasCursor.execute``. Will edit in my OP

Comment: Sure ... you just use more than one database-connection object.

Comment: @MikeRobinson That is what we're doing here, however, it seems the queries in run with ``DevCursorChange`` are just being disregarded.

Comment: Have you tried making the DevCursor the buffered one? _I'm suspecting iterating  over it does not retrieve all rows from the connection, causing the first DevCursorChange.execute to interfere with it's results._

Comment: @Uueerdo Yeah, we've attempted making them all buffered, without any more luck

Comment: Have you confirmed the loop iterates, and has the expected number of iterations?

Comment: @Uueerdo Well, I guess that's where the problem lies, as it doesn't iterate even once, whilst it should iterate about 150 times. This makes me believe it's not catching the condition for the loop at all.

Comment: I'm out of ideas with my limited Python knowledge, and would just be guessing at this point (try fetchall() and loop over it's results?), so I guess someone else will have to chime in.